# "Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorrt

I'm trying train a Deep Reinforcement Learning model, but Tensorflow can't use my GPU, when I execute the .py, I obtain the next message:

> 2023-03-22 11:39:05.556296: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> 2023-03-22 11:39:05.556340: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> 2023-03-22 11:39:05.556347: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.

I have installed the drivers of my GPU, cuda, tensorRT...

Comment: TensorRT is not required for GPU support. That is not your problem.

Comment: Please verify with these tested [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) if you have installed the correct tensorflow, python version with the compatible version of CUDA and cuDNN for GPU support in your system. Also ensure that you have set the path correctly after installing these [softwares](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux_1) for GPU setup.